# flex plug-in for myeclipse

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, myeclipse

Is there any plug-in for flex in order to develop it on myeclipse?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since myEclipse is essentially Eclipse, there are couple of options.

1. Flash Builder 4 by Adobe http://www.adobe.com/products/flashbuilder/
2. FDT http://www.fdt.powerflasher.com/developer-tools/fdt/home/
3. Not Eclipse plugin, but worth trying. FlashDevelop, free but stand-alone application http://www.flashdevelop.org

Also I heard people using ASDT plugin http://sourceforge.net/projects/aseclipseplugin/, never tried it but I guess it's also worth mentioning.